# How do I redirect a web URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http-redirect

I want to redirect users who enter this website URL: 
http://www.myWebsite.com/bananas

to: 
http://www.myWebsite.com/fruits/bananas

I cant test it because I'm sending this to somebody.

I have these but I don't know for sure which one works:

```
RedirectMatch 301 http://www.myWebsite.com/bananas(.*) http://www.myWebsite.com/food/bananas $1





Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewriterule ^bananas(.*)$ http://www.myWebsite.com/food/bananas $1 [r=301,nc]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please specify if you want to redirect or rewrite. The rules you are using serve different purposes and you used both in your example.

1. **Redirect**: Actually load a different site when entering the url (end up at url and content of /fruits/bananas)
2. **Rewrite**: Url stays the same but server provides rewritten content (url stays at /bananas, but show /fruits/bananas content)
   http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Also it is not clear if you only want one single directory to be redirected or all files that are contained in that directory.

Checkout this as a guide: http://www.htaccessredirect.net/

Comment: Thank you. when you say: "without loading anything new", do you mean that the page will display /fruits/bananas but the URL line will stay /bananas ?

Comment: Yes, the RewriteRule specifies how the entered Url (e.g. /bananas) is actually served by the server (/fruits/bananas). Url stays /bananas but the content of /fruits/bananas is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for

```
Redirect 301 /bananas http://www.myWebsite.com/fruits/bananas
```

The HTTP 301 stands for `Moved Permanently`.

I haven't tested it, though.